# 3rd Party Authentication / OpenID With iOS and RESTful API

Tags: facebook, api, rest, openid, loopbackjs

I was reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695205/stateless-restful-api-and-3rd-party-authentication) here among others. I have an iOS app which connects to a LoopbackJS API. Users can register manually but I also want to allow Facebook authentication. I added the Facebook SDK and I can get a token and all that, but...

1) What is the best, most secure way to authenticate them with my existing API?

2) Do I use their Facebook information to create an account?

3) If so what do I use as the password?

4) Sites like Tinder don't ask me to add my own password, what are they doing? Storing some version of my token as the password in their API?

Loopback has Passport built in but the documentation is terrible and confusing and I am having a lot of trouble getting it to work with the iOS Facebook SDK.